# is it possible to replace MarkerClusterer with MarkerClustererPlus in the gem ‘gmaps4rails’?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmaps4rails

I would like to continue using the gem ‘gmaps4rails’ but use MarkerClustererPlus instead of MarkClusterer ... is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the syntax seems to be the same, you should only disable the auto inclusion of the js files:

```
<%= gmaps( data_hash, true)
```

Then add these files yourself in your page and include the MarkerClustererPlus instead of the drfault one.

Answer (score 0):

In your Gemfile, add this line:

gem 'markerclustererplus-rails'

You can include it by adding the following to your javascript file:

//= require markerclusterer

reference - https://github.com/RogerE/markerclustererplus-rails